# how to use time values in an IF function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using this formula to work out values more than 40 hours and Excel says I am missing parentheses

```
=IF(J10>=40:00,J10-40:00,IF(J10<=40:00,0))+IF(S10>=40:00,S10-40:00,IF(S10<=40:00,0))
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your question is poorly formatted and missing important details. Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question to include pertinent details.

Answer (score 0):

The formula's parentheses are fine, but you can't use a time value like that.

Write the value 40:00 into cell A1, then you can use

```
=IF(J10>=A1,J10-A1,IF(J10<=A1,0))+IF(S10>=A1,S10-A1,IF(S10<=A1,0))
```

Or use the numerical representation of 40 hours, which is the number `1.66666666666667`

```
=IF(J11>=1.66666666666667,J11-1.66666666666667,IF(J11<=1.66666666666667,0))+IF(S11>=1.66666666666667,S11-1.66666666666667,IF(S11<=1.66666666666667,0))
```

Or use the Time() function like this

```
=IF(J12>=TIME(40,0,0),J12-TIME(40,0,0),IF(J12<=TIME(40,0,0),0))+IF(S12>=TIME(40,0,0),S12-TIME(40,0,0),IF(S12<=TIME(40,0,0),0))
```

Comment: Teylyn can I send you the entire line so you will understand my question more clear

Comment: @sherri Please edit your question to provide more detail. Then post a comment here to notify me of the change.